How to match router objects with a specific key attribute
example:I want to match all router leaf nodes that do not contain children.
I tried these methods, but they didn't work. Why?
rule:
  kind: object
  all:
    - kind: property_identifier
      regex: ^path$
    - kind: property_identifier
      regex: ^name$
    - kind: property_identifier
      regex: ^component$
  not:
    kind: property_identifier
    regex: ^children$


this is playground demo: rule of playground
I expect to match the following data：
routes = [
  {
    path: '/home',
    name: 'home',
    component: HomeComponent,
  },
  // is detail leaf nodes
  {
    path: '/detail-a',
    name: 'DetailA',
    component: () => import('./DetailA'),
    meta: {},
  },
  {
    path: '/detail-b',
    name: 'DetailB',
    component: () => import('./DetailB'),
  },
  // is order leaf nodes
  {
    path: '/order-a',
    name: 'OrderA',
    component: () => import('./OrderA'),
    meta: {},
  },
  {
    path: '/order-b',
    name: 'OrderB',
    component: () => import('./OrderA'),
    meta: {},
  },
]


Can you add an example code you want to match?

Thank you for response. I added the demo and the expected results.

Thanks for using ast-grep.
The problem of your rule is not using has and misunderstanding of all.
Let's break it down. First
rule:
  kind: object
  all:
  - kind: property_identifier
    regex: ^path$

Will never match anything. According to the doc of rule object,

A node will match a rule if and only if it satisfies all fields in the rule object.

Thus an AST node can not be both object and property_identifier
Instead, has can be used to match an object that has a specific property_identifier.
rule:
  kind: object
  all:
  - has:
      kind: property_identifier
      regex: ^path$
      stopBy: end

Note you also need to add more property_identifier constraints to the rule.  A rule like has: { all: [...]}  will not work. This is because an AST node cannot has a child or a descendant that satisfies all conditions.
Instead, it should match an object matching all the conditions that has children of certain kinds.
Finally, the rule can be used with not to exclude children field.
rule:
  kind: object
  all:
  - has:
      kind: property_identifier
      regex: ^path$
      stopBy: end
  - has:
      kind: property_identifier
      regex: ^name$
      stopBy: end
  - has:
      kind: property_identifier
      regex: ^component$
      stopBy: end
  not:
    has: 
      kind: property_identifier
      regex: ^children$
      stopBy: end

The final playground for the rule.
